# Extracting multiple numbers from a string into variables

Tags: regex, ruby

Given a string that contains two numbers inside brackets, how can I assign these numbers to variables to have code clean. The "POINT(1.21212 2.51212) it is string returned from postgresql/postgis.

```
a, b = "POINT(1.21212 2.51212)". ???
```

and result:

```
a = 1.21212
b = 2.51212
```

Regards

Comment: It would be nice to provide a little more context. This is a very abstract problem, and it's difficult to know if there's a better suggestion without knowing more detail.

Comment: Or of course, it might literally just be an abstract problem for the sake the puzzle, which is also fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do:

```
a, b = "CAR(1.2 2.5)".scan(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/).map(&:to_f)
```

`scan` will find any occurrence of the number in the string, and `map(&:to_f)` converts that occurrence into a float number. You might want to Use BigDecimal instead, depending on your needs.

But, one thing that raises the eyebrow here - why would you need to do that? Are you writing your own parser?

Comment: @CarySwoveland - `scan` behaviour various massively depending on whether there are captured groups or not. With capturing groups it returns an array of arrys of matched groups rather than matched string. So in this case: `[[".2"], [".5"]]` instead of `["1.2", "2.5"]`

Comment: @CarySwoveland Aaaand just realized I completely missed the `?` at the end of my non-capturing group which truelly means that 1) the group is not necessary 2) I misunderstood your comment 3) I need to sleep more... Added now :)